# Theorem 12.4.2 in Ratcliffe's text, Foundation of Hyperbolic Manifolds

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

[image]

**QUESTION**: So I was wondering why having a distinct collection of elements $g_i\in \Gamma$ implies that the Euclidian diameter of $g_iP$ tends towards zero?